# Different mysql queries depends on checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Trying to create search function, depends on checkboxes it can find title, text and tags of the article

Here is my function, but it use several requests to DB, and i am trying to make w/ one request ;)

```
public function search_articles($title=NULL, $tag=NULL, $text=NULL)
{
    $articles = array();
    if ($tag !== NULL) {
        $this->db->select('articles.*')
            ->from('articles')
            ->from('tags')
            ->from('articles_tags_rel')
            ->where('articles.id = articles_tags_rel. article_id')
            ->where('articles_tags_rel.tag_id = tags.id')
            ->where('tags.name', $tag);
        $articles = array_merge($articles, $this->db->get()->result_array());
    }
    if ($text !== NULL) {
        $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('articles')
            ->like('text', $text)
            ->order_by('title');
        $articles = array_merge($articles, $this->db->get()->result_array());
    }
    if ($title !== NULL) {
        $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('articles')
            ->like('title', $title)
            ->order_by('title');
        $articles = array_merge($articles, $this->db->get()->result_array());
    }
    $articles = unique_multidim_array($articles, 'id'); // TODO: better to get unique using mysql then php?
    return $articles;
}
```

I have  3 tables in DB: articles - id, text; tags - id, name; articles_tag_rel - article_id, tag_id

How is it better to check what checkboxes user click and how to build query to get articles w/ 1 request?

Ty

UPD: did this myself :) here is new version:

```
/**
 * Search articles by text/title/tags depends on checkboxes values
 * @param array $data of checkboxes values, keys can be 'tag'/'title'/'text'
 * @return array $articles of non-repeat articles
 */
public function search_articles($data)
{
    $str = "";
    if (isset($data['tag'])) {
        $this->db
                ->select('articles.*')
                ->from('articles')
                ->from('tags')
                ->from('articles_tags_rel')
                ->where('articles.id = articles_tags_rel. article_id')
                ->where('articles_tags_rel.tag_id = tags.id')
                ->where('tags.name', $data['tag']);
        $str = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
        unset($data['tag']);
    }
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $this->db
                    ->select('*')->from('articles')
                    ->like($key, $value);
            $str .= (!$str) ? $this->db->get_compiled_select() : " UNION ". $this->db->get_compiled_select();
    }
    $articles = $this->db->query($str)->result_array();
    return $articles;
}
```